# Accessing data from Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

First, I'm just a rookie and it's my 3rd day work. I created a object called

- Merchandise

  a page and wrote a class to control the page, below are some details of them

1.The Page

```
<apex:dataTable border="1px" value="{!searchResults}" var="pitem" rowClasses="odd,even">
          <apex:column headerValue="Product" width="100">
              <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.name}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="  Price" width="70">
              <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.Price__c}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price" width="200">
              <apex:outputtext value="{!pitem.Unit_Price__c}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price" width="200">
              <apex:outputtext value="{! IF(pitem.Price__c > 15, 'Unit Price is normal','Unit Price is too low')}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:column>
     </apex:dataTable>
```

2.Class

```
public class Bo_Test{
    public static integer age = 20;
    public string city{get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
    public static List<Merchandise__c> searchResults {get;set;}
    
   public Bo_Test(){
    searchResults = new List<Merchandise__c>();
    String queryString = 'SELECT Price__c, Name, Unit_Price__c from Merchandise__c';
    searchResults = Database.query(queryString);
    //this.city = "Jersey City";
    //name  = "Bobo";   
}
    


    public PageReference sayHello(){
        return null;
    } 
}
```

In the page display, there are no data showed from the Merchandise object(actually there are a lot), did I do it wrong way? how to access the data by editing the apex class?

The point is, Until now I still have no ideas about the page and class related to each other, does it call the default constructor? any kind of suggestions are welcomed!!

Help me! I'm looking forward hearing from you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, are you **binding** the page to `Bo_Test` controller ?

```
<apex:page controller="Bo_Test"> 
   <apex:dataTable .......
```

If that is not your problem, try changing your class by

```
public class Bo_Test{
    public List<Merchandise__c> searchResults {get;set;}

    public Bo_Test(){
        searchResults = [SELECT Price__c, Name, Unit_Price__c from Merchandise__c];
    }
 }
```

Notice that I've removed the static property to searchResults.

*In addition* this initialization is not need.

```
searchResults = new List<Merchandise__c>();
```

Comment: that's really helpful, by the way, do you know how to insert a record with master detail relationship? my new question posted on   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888266/make-a-select-object-field-in-salsforce