# make a select object field in salsforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

First, I'm just a beginner in salesforce and started to learn visualforce page using apex,

basically I have the default object "people", and many records in it

now is to write a "payment" visual page to allow people to select the people record

they are master-details relationship, what apex tag should I use in both page side and apex class? similar like time selector one below:

page code:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!proxyObject.closeDate}"/>
```

class:

```
opportunity o = new Opportunity();

public Opportunity getProxyObject() { return o; }
```

Can any body help me with it? Any kind of suggestions are welcomed!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have lookup field from opportunity to people just write on page something like this  `<apex:inputField value="{!proxyObject.people__c}"/>`

Comment: that's cool! but now I have a B with master detail A, I want to get the value 'balance' in A via B, how should I do? I tried A__c temp = B__c.A__c, but it turns out wrong, can you give me some hints?